# Tweet from an android service

Tags: android, twitter, android-service, twitter4j

I'd like to tweet from my android service class. I have implemented tweeting from an android activity class and it is working perfectly fine. However, from a service class i'm not able to do the same. Here is the snippet I used. I have used twitter4j library.
The status is just a string.

```
                    ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
                    builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(Constants.CONSUMER_KEY);
                    builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(Constants.CONSUMER_SECRET);

                    SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;

                    mSharedPreferences = getApplicationContext()
                            .getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);

                    final String PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN = "oauth_token";
                    final String PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET = "oauth_token_secret";

                    // Access Token
                    String access_token = mSharedPreferences.getString(
                            PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN, "");
                    // Access Token Secret
                    String access_token_secret = mSharedPreferences.getString(
                            PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET, "");

                    AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(access_token,
                            access_token_secret);
                    Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(builder.build())
                            .getInstance(accessToken);

                    // Update status
                    twitter4j.Status response = twitter.updateStatus(status);
```

Comment: What's the error you get? Logcat please!

Comment: Nothing on the logcat. I'm just printing the OAUTH token I get after login. But no errors on logcat.

Comment: Just post some logs at varies check points and debug it. Check whether `twitter.updateStatus(status);` is getting executed.